# Area-global filters in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas, action-filter

Since it doesn't appear to be supported natively, what's the recommended way of implementing global filters on a per-area basis?

Comment: Putting the filter on every controller of that area? :) But seriously, do you mean `ActionFilters`?

Comment: I do, but as of MVC 3 `ActionFilters` are a specific implementation of the broader `IFilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom [IFilterProvider](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html).

Comment: That should do it! Good thinking

Answer (score 9):

The reason it's not supported natively is because we want to discourage developers from doing it.  Areas are not associated with controllers; they're associated *with routes*.  We wanted to discourage developers from trying to apply authorization or other security-sensitive filters to areas since they can be bypassed.

See [How can we set authorization for a whole area in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319157/how-can-we-set-authorization-for-a-whole-area-in-asp-net-mvc/2320419#2320419) for more information.

Comment: For an MVC 4 update, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

Comment: _"Areas are not associated with controllers"_ -- funny that I can see a controllers folder in each area. Controllers are **always** associated with an area: either the "root" area, or a custom area. So I disagree. A common example of areas is to create an "Admin" area  - guess what filter you'd want to apply globally to just that area.

Comment: @Quango Your assumption is incorrect.  See also my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319157/how-can-we-set-authorization-for-a-whole-area-in-asp-net-mvc/2320419#2320419, which demonstrates that controllers don't belong to areas.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that: I now understand what you mean better, and withdraw my previous comment. It sounds like the controller factory is being too helpful in matching stuff up.