# Create specific attribute for area in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I registered some filters in `Global.asax.cs` file which looks like

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters( GlobalFilterCollection filters )
{
         filters.Add( new MyAttribute() );
         filters.Add( new AuthenticateAttribute() );
}
```

This thing will apply these two attributes to all controllers from project.

Now, I want to create a specific attribute and register it ( I don't know where and how, maybe like as above method) but it must be available only for `area` side.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5700326/1664356