# How to create a filter that apply to an entire area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using C# MVC5 and I have created an `AccessAttribute` to define what page each user can access based on his permission.

In my application there is an [Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) called Administration that only the "admin" user can access.

**Question** : Is it possible to apply a global filter to this area, similar to how we apply global filter to an entire project?

**Current Solution** : Add the `AccessAttribute` to every class definition in the admin section.

**Problem with that solution** : If I simply forget to add the attribute to the class definition, an attacker could gain access to the admin section.

Comment: You can create a base controller for the area, and put the annotation on that, and then inherit from it all controllers in that area - see second answer on [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319157/how-can-we-set-authorization-for-a-whole-area-in-asp-net-mvc/2320419#2320419)

Comment: @Carl Thx for comment but I wouldn't call that a solution. What is the difference in time between applying an attribute to my entire controller or inherit from a base controller. Also, inheriting just to apply an attribute sounds wrong. If there is no solution I will just write the attribute above each class definition.

Comment: no, i didn't think it was a solution hence a comment and not an answer - just another option :) the only other thing I've come across is [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700295/area-global-filters-in-mvc-3) but never done this myself.

Comment: @Gudradain, I'd say you're wrong that the idea provided by Carl is not a solution. In fact, it better solves your concern than applying the attribute. See, if you build a base controller **just for the admin pages**, you'll soon find other items to place in that base controller that help your workflow. It is very much a good solution.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud And how am I more likely to remember to inherit from a base class than to put a 1 line attribute? I'm thinking about security first then about ease of development.

Comment: @Gudradain, let me reiterate; **you'll soon find other items to place in that base controller that help your workflow.** When this happens, guess what you won't forget when building an admin page?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud A base class might simply **help me to remember** and not **force me to remember**. See my answer... If I need a base class, I will create one. As to whether or not the best way to replace a 1 line attribute is inheriting from a base class I guess we will disagree...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

My primary concern is the security : I don't want to forget a single attribute (or inheritance).

So, the logical answer is to create a global filter that block all access and then to override this attribute per controller. Just like `AuthorizeAttribute` and `AllowAnonymousAttribute` work.